# Apply filters while recording video using UIImagePickerController

Tags: ios, swift, uiimagepickercontroller

I have customised camera controls and add some custom UI on camera overlay of UIImagePickerController, now i want to add filter functionality while recording video. I have searched a lot but I only got filter related instructions or code for static or captured UIImage, but I want that on video while I am capturing it.

So does it is possible to apply filter while recording video using UIImagePickerController?

Comment: did you found any solution for this?